# De-serialize JSON list of JSON serialized objects

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

I'm trying to de-serialize a `List<string>` which is in fact a `List<myClass>` whose objects have been serialized. Example:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<MyThirdClass> myThirdClass = new List<MyThirdClass>(new[] { new MyThirdClass { RoleId = 123, RoleName = "123" }, new MyThirdClass { RoleId = 234, RoleName = "234" } });
    List<MySecondSerializedClass> mySecondSerializedClass = new List<MySecondSerializedClass>();
    foreach (MyThirdClass thirdClass in myThirdClass)
    {
        MySecondSerializedClass secondClass = new MySecondSerializedClass { Roles = new List<string>() };
        foreach (MyThirdClass tClass in myThirdClass)
        {
            secondClass.Roles.Add(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tClass));
        }
        mySecondSerializedClass.Add(secondClass);
    }
    MyFirstSerializedClass firstClass = new MyFirstSerializedClass
    {
        Id = 1,
        Name = "1",
        Roles = mySecondSerializedClass
    };

    string serializedFirstClass = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(firstClass, Formatting.Indented);
    MyFirstNonSerializedClass nonSerializedFirstClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyFirstNonSerializedClass>(serializedFirstClass);
}

public class MyFirstSerializedClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<MySecondSerializedClass> Roles { get; set; }
}

public class MyFirstNonSerializedClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<MySecondNonSerializedClass> Roles { get; set; }
}

public class MySecondSerializedClass
{
    public List<string> Roles { get; set; }
}

public class MySecondNonSerializedClass
{
    public List<MyThirdClass> Roles { get; set; }
}

public class MyThirdClass
{
    public int RoleId { get; set; }
    public string RoleName { get; set; }
}
```

`serializedFirstClass` returns a JSON like this:

```
{
  "Id": 1,
  "Name": "1",
  "Roles": [
    {
      "Roles": [
        "{\"RoleId\":123,\"RoleName\":\"123\"}",
        "{\"RoleId\":234,\"RoleName\":\"234\"}"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Roles": [
        "{\"RoleId\":123,\"RoleName\":\"123\"}",
        "{\"RoleId\":234,\"RoleName\":\"234\"}"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

And trying to de-serialize it throws an Exception with the message:

> Error converting value "{"RoleId":123,"RoleName":"123"}" to type 'ConsoleApplication1.Program+MyThirdClass'. Path 'Roles[0].Roles[0]', line 7, position 47.

Is there something I am doing wrong or any way to recursively de-serialize the MyFirstSerializedClass to MyFirstNonSerializedClass?

Comment: Why external roles aren't escaped while internal are?

Comment: @abatishchev I'd guess that's because I serialize the roles as string and then re-serialize them

Comment: The declare Roles in MySecondNonSerializedClass as List<string>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a single set of classes and an optional [`JsonConverter`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter.htm) for `MyThirdClass` that reads the current JSON token as a string literal, then uses a nested serializer to deserialize that string literal from JSON as an instance of `MyThirdClass`.  Add the converter to  [JsonSerializerSettings.Converters](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings_Converters.htm) when you want to serialize or deserialize your class as an embedded string; leave it out to serialize as an object.

Thus:

```
public class MyFirstClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<MySecondClass> Roles { get; set; }
}

public class MySecondClass
{
    public List<MyThirdClass> Roles { get; set; }
}

public class MyThirdClass
{
    public int RoleId { get; set; }
    public string RoleName { get; set; }
}

public sealed class MyThirdClassStringConverter : JsonConverter
{
    readonly JsonSerializerSettings settings;

    public MyThirdClassStringConverter() : this(null) { }

    public MyThirdClassStringConverter(JsonSerializerSettings settings)
    {
        this.settings = settings;
    }

    JsonSerializer GetInnerSerializer()
    {
        var innerSerializer = JsonSerializer.CreateDefault(settings);
        for (int i = innerSerializer.Converters.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            if (innerSerializer.Converters[i] is MyThirdClassStringConverter)
                innerSerializer.Converters.RemoveAt(i);
        return innerSerializer;
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(MyThirdClass).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
            return null;
        var innerSerializer = GetInnerSerializer();
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.String)
        {
            var s = reader.Value.ToString();
            using (var innerReader = new StringReader(s))
                return innerSerializer.Deserialize(innerReader, objectType);
        }
        else
        {
            return innerSerializer.Deserialize(reader, objectType);
        }
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var innerSerializer = GetInnerSerializer();
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        using (var innerWriter = new StringWriter(sb))
            innerSerializer.Serialize(innerWriter, value);
        writer.WriteValue(sb.ToString());
    }
}
```

Then, use it as follows:

```
var stringSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings { Converters = new[] { new MyThirdClassStringConverter() } };

// Deserialize JSON where MyThirdClass objects are embedded strings
var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyFirstClass>(stringJson, stringSettings);

// Re-serialize to JSON where MyThirdClass objects are objects
var newNonStringJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(root, Formatting.Indented);
// Re-serialize to JSON where MyThirdClass objects are embedded strings
var newStringJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(root, Formatting.Indented, stringSettings);
```

Note that the converter should *not* be applied to `MyThirdClass` directly using `[JsonConverter(typeof(MyThirdClassStringConverter))]` as infinite recursion would result.  The converter's `ReadJson()` method tests to see whether the current token is a string or object and adapts accordingly, so it can be used to deserialize JSON in either format.

Example [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/osJ8HN).

Comment: Accepting your answer because it's the most complete answer, but I went another path with my classes that does not double-serialize objects

Answer (score 1):

You're expecting to deserialize `string` to `MyThirdClass` structure which is not possible.

**They in fact not the same.**

List of string will be serialized to

**"**\"SomeProperty\":\"SomePropertyValue\"**"**,
**"**\"SomeProperty2\":\"SomePropertyValue\"**"**

While *List of CustomClass* will be

"SomeProperty":"SomePropertyValue",
"SomeProperty2":"SomeProperty2Value"

Comment: So how can I serialize it in such a way I can later de-serialize it? This double serialization is for storing in an ATS (Azure Table Storage) table. Some sample code would be great

Answer (score 1):

When serializing you convert a `MyThirdClass` to a string. 
When deserializing you need the inverse transformation. Add an implicit conversion from string to your type.

```
public static implicit operator MyThirdClass(string s)
{
  // when serializing indented =>
  // return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<B3>(s, new JsonSerializerSettings() { Formatting = Formatting.Indented});
  // otherwise
  return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<B3>(s);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I ended up removing the serialized classes and followed a different approach.